# Acucobol Grid - how to wrap text in a cell?

Tags: grid, cobol

I am using acucobol GT and have a program that draws a grid.

I has its display-columns arranged like this:

```
display-columns = (1,5,15,25,40,55,75,145,156,171,191,206)
virtual-width = (226)
vpadding = (500)
```

One of these columns has cells that might contain a lot of text or not much text at all. Therefore I don't want to make them too wide as they would take a lot of space, but I also want all text to be visible. How do I make it so the cell displays all the text by wrapping it in the cell? I used vpadding to make sure there is enough space to do this, but I don't know how to make the text wrap. All I can find in the documentation is this bit:

> A column identifies a particular cell in a record. By default, a record occupies one row in a grid, but you can arrange for a record to wrap around to the next row when it passes the right edge of the grid. When this occurs, a record occupies more than one row in the grid.

This leads me to believe that this should be possible. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That would not be what the acu-docs talk about, but did you try to manually insert a line break `x'0A'`/`x'0D0A'` in the row?

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the suggestion! I haven't tried that and I'll consider it an option if I don't find another way to do it. The problem here is that the columns are automatically filled with records from a SQL database, so I'd have to do some fancy string manipulation which I don't feel comfortable with. (I can do it but it'll take time, I'm as junior a developer as they get)